# Typical ways to load backend data into Backbone Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, marionette

I'm working on a production app using Backbone Marionette. We have several different Views and Models associated with them. We also have several Controller classes which invoke and create the Views and Models. However, what is the best practice for loading in the backend data and using that data to populate the model? Is the typical process to create a blank model instance and then make an AJAX call to the backend to fill the model in? I'm interested in learning more about how people using Backbone and Marionette typically load data from their backend.

Comment: typical way is to just fetch the model (ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Backbone Docs say](http://backbonejs.org#FAQ-bootstrap) that it is better to have your Models and Collections pre populated with data from backend. See Loading Bootstrapped Models.

Comment: This is how I do it. Generally load any collections that you need right away so there is no need to wait for a "Loading..." type screen. Then load collections that you will need later on via ajax calls. Note that I generally try to load them as soon as possible. Example: If I know I am going to need a collection when the click on a Next button, then I will load it now so that when they click the next button it is instant rather than having to wait for the collection to be loaded.